# Exoplayer2 OutOfMemoryError exeption and app crash

Tags: android, out-of-memory, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

in my play console, i am getting this crash report how can I deal with it?

here is the crash report.

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:     at
>   android.media.AudioTrack.getTimestamp (AudioTrack.java:1396)    at
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.AudioTrack$AudioTrackUtilV19.updateTimestamp
>   (AudioTrack.java)       at
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.AudioTrack.maybeSampleSyncParams
>   (AudioTrack.java)       at
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.AudioTrack.getCurrentPositionUs
>   (AudioTrack.java)       at
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.MediaCodecAudioRenderer.getPositionUs
>   (MediaCodecAudioRenderer.java)      at
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.updatePlaybackPositions
>   (ExoPlayerImplInternal.java)    at
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork
>   (ExoPlayerImplInternal.java)    at
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage
>   (ExoPlayerImplInternal.java)    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage
>   (Handler.java:98)       at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)     at
>   android.os.HandlerThread.run (HandlerThread.java:61)

Comment: Use less memory throughout your app.  Use heap dumps to tell what memory you're using and figure out what's leaking or growing out of control.  Usually its images.

Comment: I am playing video using exoplayer and released it resources when done with playing. and for images, i am using Picasso to handle the loading task.

Comment: 'Use heap dumps to tell what memory you're using and figure out what's leaking or growing out of control' can u please tell me more about on this?

Comment: A heap dump is a listing of everything on your heap-  basically every object that was created via new and not yet garbage collected.  What's happening is either you have a memory leak (where old objects are unable to be cleaned up) or you're using way too much and need to use less.  And you have to look over the entire app, the actual request that ran out of memory is meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

USE Exoplayer newest version library and check player different video may be problem is in your video codec.

Comment: Please add clarifications or suggestions as comment.

Comment: compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.6.1'
use this library and try video.for more detail please check this link
https://github.com/vishal105/ExoPlayerSample